# 10° rotation of a motor in 0,003125 sec

Tags: servo, motor-controller

I asked before, but I wasn't clear and after helpful answers and requesting more descriptions I explained more but nobody answered back. I don't understand electronics very well, so very sorry for my bad definitions for my previous question and for this question.

My problem is I'm going to make a project that has a motor driving a cam mechanism. The cam mechanism inertia moment is 0,001232 kg m<sup>2</sup> and I want to rotate the motor between 0° and 160° clockwise and anticlockwise not full 360°. I want to rotate in 10° steps per 0,003125 Sec. I can rotate 70°, 80°, 90° degree or only 10° or 160°. if it is wanted 160° it will take 0,003125 X 16 = 0,05 s. 
If it is 20° duration is 0,00312 X 2 = 0,00624 and motor stops immediately.

So what is my motor torque, speed or kW? What kind of a motor should I use?
Thanks for your any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure physics/mechanics question, no electronics needed. But EEs are versatile, so it can be answered here.

'Stops immediately'? Immediately is zero time, so will require infinite power. I'm sure you realise that's not going to happen.

You need therefore to think about a finite time where the motor accelerates to speed, and a similar braking time at the end.

Let's add one 0.003125 time step (= ts = 1/320th second) to each movement, so 10 degrees takes 2*ts, 100 degrees takes 11*ts. A one step movement therefore accelerates to travel speed during the first ts, moving 5 degrees, and brakes to zero during the second ts, travelling a further 5 degrees. If it's shifting 100 degrees, it accelerates through 5 degrees during the first ts, travels 90 degrees in the next 9 steps, and brakes during the last one for the last 5 degrees of travel.

Travel speed w is therefore 1 circle in 36*ts = 8.88 rps = 533 rpm = 55.8 rad/s.

Acceleration a, if assumed to be linear over one ts, is w/ts = 55.8/ts = 18.8k rad/s.

Torque T over the acceleration time step is a*MOI = 18.8k * 0.001232 = 23Nm.

Motor power P at the end of the acceleration time step is T*w = 1360 Watts, or a mean power of about 700 W over that time.

I don't know what motor you were hoping to use, but (after 'Jaws') I think you're going to need a bigger motor. Or a lighter cam mechanism. Or a slower operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer. So I should choose a servo or step motor that is 1,360 kW. 
Which is the best servo or step motor for my project?

Comment: No, I'd be more inclined to redo the sums for 160 degrees in 50mS with constant acceleration/deceleration, which yields a peak power of 613W, and then allow your smaller movements to take the same 50mS, or at least not get faster linearly. At this power, a servo motor is a better option than a stepper motor. A DC brushless, with Hall sensors, will be more compact than a brushed motor, but will be trickier to control.

Comment: I couldn't understand that you found 1360 Watts but you propose a mean power of about 700W. Is this 1360 Watts peak power? If I found 2000 Watts  would I choose 2000/2 = 1000 Watts?

Comment: @adem Well, that's engineers for you. My thought processes were thus. The peak power is 1360, so if all my assumptions are correct, the mean power is 1360/2 = 680.00000. However, the acceleration won't be linear, I've made assumptions that the OP hasn't asked for, so I'll be lucky if that answer is within a factor of 2, so I'm going to round it to one significant figure, and preface it by 'about'. Hence, about 700W.

Comment: I understand now what you meant. Thank you for helping.